Google Sign In error 10 en mi aplicación publicada en la Play Store
tengo un problema con mi aplicación. Tengo un proyecto de Android Studio en el cual agregué la funcionalidad de iniciar sesión con Google (con un correo corporativo especifico), para ello cree el proyecto en Google Cloud con el paquete y la huella SHA1 correspondiente al release de mi aplicación.
En sí. Mi aplicación funciona correctamente tanto en APK como en el modo de desarrollo de Android Studio (Emulador y dispositivo)
Se autentica con normalidad y cumple con su función. El problema surge cuando subo la actualización de mi aplicación a la Play Store.
Ya que al instalarla e intentar iniciar sesion con el dominio especifico, me arroja un "error" 10 (signInResult:failed code=10)
esta es la funcion:
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            String emailGoogle = account.getEmail();

            CompletableFuture<String> futureResponse = sendEmailToWebService(emailGoogle);

            futureResponse.thenAccept(response -> {
                Log.d("WebService", "Respuesta exitosa: " + response);
                cargarData(emailGoogle, "000000000", "00-000000");

            }).exceptionally(error -> {
                Log.e("WebService", "Error en la respuesta: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(LoginCarnetActivity.this, "Error al enviar email al webservice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            });

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("LoginCarnetActivity", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            Log.e("LoginCarnetActivity", "Error details: ", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al iniciar sesión con Google", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

Así agregué la funcionalidad a mi aplicación:
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id)) //agregué esta linea para intentar resolver este mismo problema y no se arregló
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

Después de buscar en varios foros y videos, donde decían que eso resolvía mi problema pero aun no se arregla.
Quise probar usando FireBase pero como ya existe el proyecto en Google Cloud no puede usarse la misma huella y no puedo eliminar el proyecto de Google Cloud ya que lo maneja otra empresa que me suministró el Client ID y el JSON.
No he encontrado otras soluciones a estas que mencioné (.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id)) y FireBase) así que si alguien tiene alguna solución seria de mucha ayuda, gracias.

normalmente ese error es porque no esta la firma del release en sha-1 me parece. debes de darlo de alta en tu proyecto de google firebase: esto te servira mejor: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/multi-factor?hl=es-419#:~:text=Abre%20Firebase%20console.,agregar%20el%20hash%20SHA%E2%80%911.

logré solucionar el problema, simplemente agregando la Huella SHA-1 de Certificado de la clave de firma de aplicación de la consola de Google a Google Cloud, finalmente quedando con la del release y con Certificado de la clave de firma de aplicación.

sos el mismo usuario que hizo la pregunta???

si, tuve un problema con la cuenta y cree 2 sin querer

Listo.. ya pedi que te fusionaran todo.. pero tene en cuenta como funciona el sitio.. es una respuesta por pregunta (por cada uno.. )... ahora cuando arreglen tu usuario, acepta tu respuesta valida, borra la otra y arregla la pregunta...

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

Mi aplicación funciona correctamente tanto en APK como en el modo de
desarrollo de Android Studio (Emulador y dispositivo) Se autentica con
normalidad y cumple con su función. El problema surge cuando subo la
actualización de mi aplicación a la Play Store.

Tu API de Google está funcionando en desarrollo, ya que registraste tu certificado del Keystore de desarrollo para usar la API, pero debes agregar también el que usas para firmar la app cuando es subida a Google Play (Para este caso debes obtener la huella del certificado SHA-1
), incluso aquí también debes registar los certificados SHA-1 de otros desarrolladores para que puedan usar la API:


Con respecto al error que indicas:

"error" 10 (signInResult:failed code=10)

Es precisamente causado porque no puedes ejecutar la API porque no has registrado el certificado SHA-1 en tu API Key desde https://console.cloud.google.com
